# Measuring the distance of detected objects in a 2D image/video

Tags: 2d, object-detection, distance, yolo

I have trained a **YOLO pose estimation model** to detect monkeys in videos. I have 20h + video footage from a stabilized 2D camera in a cage with about 12 monkeys. The detection and key point estimation works fine, but now I want to extend the research by adding social proximity, but I can't get my head around it.

#### I have researched several possibilities:

- Dist_YOLO (https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/12/3/1354)
- Measuring distance (https://blog.roboflow.com/computer-vision-measure-distance/)
- Object Detector (https://github.com/noorkhokhar99/Real-Time-Object-Detection-and-Distance-Measurement-with-Computer-Vision/blob/main/objectdetector.py)

But I couldn't find a method yet that works in my case.

#### Some specifications:

- There is a reference object in the videos (a wooden plank) that is static and always the same size (~1m^2), and I know its exact coordinates and size in pixels.
- I know the (average) monkey's size (in real life and in pixels).
- I can also get the distance between the camera and the reference object.

Can someone help me to get on the right track? What's the best option to measure the distance between the monkeys? (The amount of monkeys in a frame ranges from 0 to 12).